# Swift Bug or Coding Error? For Loops in Structs

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, for-loop, struct

So I am trying to make an iOS app that checks prime numbers in an input field as practice. I refactored my code to have a struct specifically for calculation functions like isPrime. For some reason my for loops is not working correctly when its in the struct. It works if I refactored it back into the controller.

```
func isPrime(number:Int) -> Bool{
    let start = 2
    for var i = number-1; i > 1; i-- {
        if (number % i == 0){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The debugger thingy gives back these inputs:
*Types 12 into text field*

---

number = 12

i = 14070095816392014214

---

Why is my variable i in the for loops so damn large? I also tested  putting a stray variable inside the function and it does the same thing (ex; start_int = 14214124123232423)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try printing the value of your number variable inside the function?

Your logic seems to be reversed. if a number x is divisible by another number less than x, then x is not prime. You have returned true if x is divisible. it should be false.